# Understanding space leak with Arrow

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, arrows

I am having difficulty understanding the space leak in Hudak's paper "plugging a space leak with arrow"
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066107005919.

1) What exactly does O(n) space complexity mean? The total memory allocated with respect to input size? What about garbage collection along the way?

2) If the definition in 1) holds, how is it that in page 34, they say if dt is constant, the signal type is akin to list type and runs in constant space? Doesn't integralC still create 1 unit of space at each step, totally n units, that is, still O(n)?

3) I totally do not understand why time complexity is O(n^2). I do have an inkling of what needs to be evaluated (i', i'', i''' in picture below), but how is that O(n^2)?

The image represents the evaluation steps I have drawn in lambda graph notation. Each step sees its structure ADDED to the overall scope rather than REPLACING whatever is in it. Square denotes pointer, so square(i') in step 2 denotes i' block in step 1 for example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have only glanced at the paper briefly, but will do my best.

1. As usual, space complexity means than at some point in time we need to be storing that much "stuff" simultaneously in memory. GC says we can recover memory from variables we no longer need, but here we need to be remembering `O(n)` stuff, the memory can't be recovered yet because we (may) still need access to any part of it. You can think of it as, reusing memory (via eg. GC) adds to time but not space complexity. Here, `n` is computing the nth value by providing n time steps (dts).
2. If `dt` is constant, then instead of the type of `C a = (a, dt -> C a)` we have `C' a = (a, C' a)` which is just a (nonempty) list. The point of the paper is that either type can be made to run in constant space, but if it were isomorphic to lists then that's a solved problem. To see why creating a new value at each step can be constant memory, consider a possible evaluation of `(iterate f)!!n`, where we store just x, then overwrite it with `f (x)`, then overwrite it with `f (f (x))`, and so on until we have `f^n(x)`, but only ever using this one cell of memory for our values (and technically a second cell to iterate up to `n`).
3. Let's consider a really simple example of evaluation giving these different complexities. Let's say we're generating a list from some seed where each item is the sum of all the previous items. To calculate each next item, we could hold the entirety of the initial part p of the list in memory (`O(Len(p))`) and sum it (`O(Len(p))`), resulting in total memory `O(n)` and run time `O(n^2) to retrieve the`n`th element - or we could observe that this is in fact the same as doubling the previous item, allowing us to use constant memory and linear time. I think the analogy section given is quite helpful - can you mechanically write out successors for the first few values and see how the two different evaluation strategies rapidly diverge in steps needed?